# How to get full server response message in Requests (or urllib3.response)?

Tags: python-requests, httpresponse, urllib3

I encountered problems with Google Sheet API these few days, all response message I can get from Requests (by way of requests_oauthlib extension) is the headers & `400 Bad Request`. Requests version is `2.19.1`. This happened with several endpoints (`v4`), like `spreadsheets.values.append`, `spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate`, `spreadsheets.values.update`, etc.

I've wasted hours making sure I have formed the correct data structure to no avail, and only then I realized I didn't get the whole response message from the API server.

It seems since `requests.Response` object that gets returned from `r = request.Request('https://httpbin.org')` is from a [`requests.HTTPAdapter`](https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/master/requests/adapters.py#L481) object, which in turn is sort of a wrapper for `urllib3.response.HTTPResponse`. So I tried to use [`r.reason`](https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/master/requests/adapters.py#L272), `r.raw._original_response`, `r.raw._body`, `r.raw.msg` which didn't give me anything but object reference & `None` (or just empty string).

Long story short, I gave up for a while & when got back to it I realized I should've tried using Google's API explorer that i've been ignoring, and it turned out there *is* an error message in the response, and the 400 error wasn't due to any bad payload/data structure form.

```
{   "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid data[0]: Requested writing within range [mysheet!A3:AH3], but tried writing to row [4]",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"   } 
}
```

My question is:

Was I wrong in how I debug connection response from requests & actually there's a method to get the full raw message from the server in requests like a full debug mode in curl? Or is this message is actually only sent if the API request comes from Google API explorer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [a closed issue in requests repo](https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/4233) from last year titled as "Suggestion: Improve the raise for status to include response body if there is one" issued by [westover](https://github.com/westover), in which he wrote:

> Looking for more details on the HTTPError exception. The API I am working with sends back a 400 but also has a text/json body in it. It would be nice if the raise_for_status() function included the response text if there was any.

He also provided a little workaround function that became the base of the reason that discussion diverted into [a pull request discussion](https://github.com/requests/requests/pull/4234):

```
import requests
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError
def expanded_raise_for_status(res):
    """
    Take a "requests" response object and expand the raise_for_status method to return more helpful errors
    @param res:
    @return: None
    """
    try:
        res.raise_for_status()
    except HTTPError as e:
        if res.text:
            raise HTTPError('{} Error Message: {}'.format(str(e.message), res.text))
        else:
           raise e
    return
```

I adopted this to my existing class & essentially as [jwodder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52392589/10254804) also pointed out, it extends/hijacks `Response.raise_for_status()` method that calls `HTTPError(RequestsException)` class whenever [`raise_for_status()`](https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/master/requests/models.py#L920) is used by users to serve the error message from server response, usually in the form of `assert response.status_code == 200, raise_for_status()`. This is achieved by adding `Response.text` (or `content` / `json` methods) to the exception message and returns the response body, instead of current code return `<self.status_code, self.reason, self.url>` which translates to `400 Bad Requests <url>`.

```
def raise_for_status(self):
    """Raises stored :class:`HTTPError`, if one occurred."""

    http_error_msg = ''
    if isinstance(self.reason, bytes):
        # We attempt to decode utf-8 first because some servers
        # choose to localize their reason strings. If the string
        # isn't utf-8, we fall back to iso-8859-1 for all other
        # encodings. (See PR #3538)
        try:
            reason = self.reason.decode('utf-8')
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            reason = self.reason.decode('iso-8859-1')
    else:
        reason = self.reason

    if 400 <= self.status_code < 500:
        http_error_msg = u'%s Client Error: %s for url: %s' % (self.status_code, reason, self.url)

    elif 500 <= self.status_code < 600:
        http_error_msg = u'%s Server Error: %s for url: %s' % (self.status_code, reason, self.url)

    if http_error_msg:
        raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
```

(In [this reply](https://github.com/requests/requests/pull/4234#issuecomment-321583961) he further laid out the reason why he thinks it's worthy of a feature, but the pull request got rejected and I think the maintainer also had good points), this might leads to other exceptions or more complications if not used thoughtfully/sparingly given the popularity of the module and the broad reasons of its usage.

Comment: The TL;DR version of the heated discussion in that rejected PR is this: "raise_for_status is meant to help with control flow, not give you a complete response body when you already have the response"

Answer (score 3):

The error message you're looking for is located in the response body.  This can be accessed with `response.text` (or `response.json()`, as the particular body is JSON).  If, as your self-answer suggests, you want to get the body from an exception raised by `raise_for_status()`, you can just go through the exception's `response` attribute: `exception.response.text` or `exception.response.json()`.

Comment: yeah, there is a function proposed to get the error body text in the link i included there (closed issue one) that i'm using to get the full JSON message. I modified it for a class method    
```
means raise_for_status() is still called, with body included
 def raise_error_message(resp):
  try:
   resp.raise_for_status()
  except HTTPError as e:
   if 400 <= resp.status_code < 500:
    http_error_msg = u'%s Error body: %s' % (resp.status_code, resp.text)
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, resp) from e
   else:
    log_d('Cannot find raise error message')
    raise e
  return
```